# listing inbounds for a security group of AWS EC2 inctances using Python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am able to list all the security group using get_all_security_groups()

I am also able to list inbound rules for a security group. but I want to see the source  also for a rule (inbound rule) using boto.

I tried to find out on google but could not see any way to see the source for a inbound rule.

if anyone know please share

Answer (score 3):

finally got solution

```
 for group in self.conn.get_all_security_groups():
        for rule in group.rules:
            print dir(rule)

            for grant in rule.grants:
                print dir(grant)
```

thanks to boto user mailing list